# Print only one property of an object that is within an an array attribute as well as a property that is a sibling to the array property in jq

Tags: json, select, jq, siblings

I have a json file that looks like so:

```json
[
  {
    "code": "1234", 
    "files": [
        {
            "fileType": "pdf",
            "url": "http://.../a.pdf"
        },
        {
            "fileType": "video",
            "url": "http://.../b.mp4"
        }
    ]
  },
  {
    "code": "4321", 
    "files": [
        {
            "fileType": "pdf",
            "url": "http://.../c.pdf"
        },
        {
            "fileType": "video",
            "url": "http://.../d.mp4"
        }
    ]
  },
  {
    "code": "9999", 
    "files": [
        {
            "fileType": "pdf",
            "url": "http://.../e.pdf"
        }
    ]
  }
]
```

I would like to print out only the files that are of `fileType` == `video` in the `files` array such that I end up with output that looks like so:

```
1234, "http://.../b.mp4"
4321, "http://.../d.mp4"
```

So far I am only able to output something that looks like this:

```
1234, "http://.../a.pdf", "http://.../b.mp4",
4321, "http://.../c.pdf", "http://.../d.mp4"
```

Using the following:

```
jq -r '.[] | select(.files[]?.fileType == "video") | [.code, .files[].url] | @csv'
```

I was wondering how I can filter the `.files[]` based on the `fileType` as I am outputting them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following pipeline makes the solution fairly self-explanatory, assuming one understands the basic syntax and the -r command-line option:

```
< input.json jq -r '
  .[]
  | .code as $code
  | .files[]
  | select(.fileType == "video")
  | "\($code), \"\(.url)\""
'
```

Comment: That’s very cool, I didn’t think to use a variable to store away the `code` while evaluating the `files`. Very straight forward, thank you!